# Safe to run Airflow upgradedb command on same Airflow version?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Airflow has an upgradedb command that needs to be run when upgrading Airflow versions. I wonder if it's safe to run even if the version is the same

Comment: What use case will that serve with the same airflow version?

Comment: None, but the point is that we want to add a step as part of our deployment and if we can call this step as a default step in our ansible playbook that'd make it really easy to do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way it works is in db.py they use the alembic command module to check the checked in files in the migrations directory https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/airflow/migrations/versions, and only make the changes if the commit version differs. But these files only get changed/added once we change the version so the upgrade db step does nothing when it's the same version/whl.
Adding it as a default step since I've verified it's safe to do so.